# Scroll CCLayer horizontally in cocos 2d in Android

Tags: android, cocos2d-android, ccscrolllayer

I am Working Android game using cocos 2d. I have Main Activity and Layers added on Main Activity in my Layer. I have 5 sprites and I have to use scroll view to scroll all sprites horizontally so user and perform further task on each sprite but I am not getting how to do this in iPhone. There are no. of classes but for Android getting nothing.

Answer (score 2):

you can add all the sprites to a single layer and then move the layer  using  "moveBy" modifier for specified distance wnen you scroll.